# Increasing Quotas and Accessing Recent Interactions in LinkedIn Community Management API

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been working with the LinkedIn Community Management API and I'm encountering two main issues:

- **Quota Limits:** I'm currently facing quota limits of about 10 requests per user per 24 hours for each endpoint. This is significantly limiting the functionality of my application. Is there a process to request an increase in these quotas? If so, could anyone guide me on how to proceed?
- **Recent Interactions Endpoint:** I am also interested in knowing if there are any specific endpoints in the API for retrieving recent user interactions (like likes and comments). This feature would be very useful for enhancing user engagement in my application.

Any guidance or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

In my attempts to work with the LinkedIn Community Management API, I've taken the following steps:

- **Reviewed the API documentation:** I scoured the official LinkedIn API documentation to understand the quota limitations and search for any mention of quota expansions or endpoints for recent interactions.
- **Made test API calls:** I've made several test calls to various endpoints to confirm the quota limits and to see if any of them would return recent interaction data.
- **Searched for similar issues:** I looked for similar questions on forums and developer communities to see if others have encountered and resolved these issues.

I was expecting to find either a clear pathway to request increased quotas or documentation on endpoints that could return recent interaction data. Unfortunately, neither was apparent from my initial research, leading to my inquiry here.

Could someone with experience in handling these specific aspects of the LinkedIn API offer some guidance?

Comment: i had the same experience a few months ago and stopped working on it because they don't have clear documentation and also this quota is really low, they just don't want developers to use their API... 

let me know if you'll find a way.